# calculate the max words per line and max lines per page

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making a book reader app using flutter,

I use the PageView widget to do pagination, and it need `childCount`
and content by index, which **max words per line and max lines per page needs to be calculated** to split a string content into pages and passing to PageView.custom.

here is the code.

```
PageView.custom(
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(70, 62, 44, 1.0),
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  maxLines: 20,
                  textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                ),
      );
    },
    childCount: 20,
    addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
    addRepaintBoundaries: false,
  ));
```

how do I calculate how many words the screen can display per page?
need some help please.

Comment: You need to actually describe a solvable problem. Showing your attempt at solving the problem helps.

Comment: Posting code of what you have created. The question as it is is very broad